# Link error for libWorklightStaticLibProject.a with Xcode 7 and MobileFirst

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

The xcode 7 update got installed for us over the weekend and now we can't build our iOS app.

The link step fails with this message:
`ld: '/Users/jenkins/build/workspace/iOS/MyProject/apps/MyApp/iphone/native/WorklightSDK/libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(WLSimpleDataSharing.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7s`

We're using MFP 7.0 and are builds are all done through the command line (mfp & xcodebuild).
Is there an update for `libWorklightStaticLibProject.a`?
Is it OK to use the "disable bitcode" workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, in fact, required to set bitcode to "no", as MobileFirst does not support bitcode at this time.

See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/
Additional iOS 9 related blog posts: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/